# Pdf form is null in itext7

Tags: .net, libreoffice, itext7, pdf-form

I have created a pdf form with LibreOffice. I exported the form as pdf. I checked the option "Create  pdf form" and I choose the FDF (or PDF) submit format. [image].

Now I try to retrieve the fields form. I am using `itext7`. Here the code I am using:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(@"file2.pdf"), new PdfWriter("result.pdf"));
var form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, false);

iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField uu = form.GetField("Category");
uu.SetValue("Auto");

document.Close();
```

The problem is `form` is null...

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Going by the code alone, this means there is no form. Could you upload your document?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the method :- form.GetField("Category");

You can use form.getFormFields() to get the list of all the form fields. Then you can check all the form fields. There could be a possibility that you might be entering the wrong form field name.